# How would I properly use the Photos framework in iOS 8 with UICollectionView, preserving image aspect ratios, like in Messages.app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uicollectionview, photosframework

I want to create a similar look to what Apple has in Messages.app, where you have a horizontal sliding view of images.

[image]

I understand in iOS 8 the best way to do this would be using the new Photos framework, and likely alongside a horizontal `UICollectionView`.

I have my `UICollectionView` pinned to a set height in my view controller storyboard, and positioned from the top, and then in `viewDidLoad` I write:

```
let assetCollectionsResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumRecentlyAdded, options: nil)
let recentlyAddedCollection = assetCollectionsResult.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
recentlyAddedFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(recentlyAddedCollection, options: nil)
```

Where `recentlyAddedFetchResult` is an instance variable on the view controller.

I then created a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that simply has a `UIImageView` pinned with Auto Layout to the cell's edges.

In the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods I have:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recentlyAddedFetchResult.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    let asset = recentlyAddedFetchResult[indexPath.row] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) { (result, info) in
        cell.imageView.image = result
    }

    return cell
}
```

However, I understand now I'd have to implement `sizeForItem`, but I'm confused how to handle that. The best way I could come up with was performing the above fetch again, but with a smaller image size as I just need the ratio, then returning a size based on that. But the fetch is asynchronous, so I'd have to save it then return it later, right?

I tried that as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let cellSize = cellSizeCache[indexPath] {
        return cellSize
    } else {
        let asset = recentlyAddedFetchResult[indexPath.row] as! PHAsset

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) { (result, info) in
            let imageRatio = result.size.width / result.size.height
            let width = 140 * imageRatio

           self.cellSizeCache[indexPath] = CGSize(width: width, height: 140.0)
           collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
        }

        return CGSize(width: 140, height: 140)
    }
}
```

But the console just gets flooded with an infinite loop of this message:

> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

But it is. The collection view is 150 tall with no section insets. Even if I remove the caching so it just returns 140x140 every time it still complains about that. Why? If I turn it down to around 70x70 it works fine, but I haven't a clue why.

On top of that, the first two images in the scroller rarely show up on the first load, only once I scroll do they.

What am I doing wrong here? There's very few tutorials on the new Photos framework, so despite my best efforts I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can use PHassets pixelWidth and pixelHeight to calculate the aspect ratio synchronous (and faster as there is no fetch for image data).

Can't help with the sizing issue so far, but can tell you that it works very similar here for me: Precalculating the width based on the aspect ratio and return the values in sizeForItemAtIndexPath like you do.

Comment: Wow, that helped enormously. If only the collection view would stop wining about sizing issues in the console that don't exist.

Comment: How many of these messages do you get?
Do they also appear for new items when you scroll or just at the beginning?

As you also see problems with the initial loading of the first items,
I would try to set a breakpoint at cellForItemAtIndexPath and see if the height of the CollectionView is already correct.

Another idea would be to log cell sizes and collectionView size in layoutSubiews to see where something goes wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you want to maintain aspect ratio and see the whole image you need `.AspectFit` not `.AspectFill`.